# TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, api, twitter, scripting, tweepy

I am using Tweepy to stream tweets from Twitter. Currently I'm trying to implement code that will disconnect the stream when a list of user ids is updated in a DB, and open a new stream with the updated list.

#### The Problem:

The implementation works fine, but somehow, `.filter()` thinks I'm passing `None` instead of a list. I am able to print the list before passing it to the method. So what am I missing?

#### More Context:

Here's the source of the error: `line 459, in filter self.body['follow'] = u','.join(follow).encode(encoding)`

Something is evaluating to None and I have no idea what it is. Somebody save me!!!

#### The Code:

```
def get_user_accounts():
    global last_number_of_accounts

    try:
        # All psycopg2 and python mumbo jumbo that gives me back a list of twitter_user_ids
        # That list is assigned to `new_user_ids`

        number_of_accounts = len(new_user_ids)

        if last_number_of_accounts == -1:
            return {"has_changed": True, "user_ids": new_user_ids, "first_connection": True}

        if number_of_accounts != last_number_of_accounts:
            return {"has_changed": True, "user_ids": new_user_ids, "first_connection": False}
        else:
            return {"has_changed": False, "user_ids": new_user_ids, "first_connection": False}
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def check_number_of_accounts():
    threading.Timer(3, check_number_of_accounts).start()
    global last_number_of_accounts
    global streamUserTweets
    new_user_ids = get_user_accounts()

    if new_user_ids['has_changed']:
        print(new_user_ids['user_ids'])  # This does not print None
        last_number_of_accounts = len(new_user_ids['user_ids'])

        if new_user_ids['first_connection']:
            # Open stream for the first time
            try:
                streamUserTweets.filter(follow=new_user_ids['user_ids'])  # So how is this none!!!
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        else:
            # Disconnect stream first, then connect with updated list
            try:
                streamUserTweets.disconnect()
                streamUserTweets.filter(follow=new_user_ids['user_ids'])
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

# TWITTER AUTHENTICATION STUFF

userTweetStreamListener = UserTweetStreamListener()
streamUserTweets = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=userTweetStreamListener)

last_number_of_accounts = -1

check_number_of_accounts()
```

#### The entire Traceback (Requested in the comments)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file.py", line 247, in <module>
    check_number_of_accounts()
  File "path/to/file.py", line 208, in check_number_of_accounts
    streamUserTweets.filter(follow=new_user_ids['user_ids'])
  File "/path/to/env/path/to/tweepy/streaming.py", line 459, in filter
    self.body['follow'] = u','.join(follow).encode(encoding)
TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **doesn't** say that you are passing `None`:

```
TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

It says that the 6th element (`item 5`) in the list/sequence you are passing is `None`. `.join()` can only join strings and that upsets the method. The output of your `print(new_user_ids['user_ids'])` line should help you find what the issue is.